# Why creating a route with angular-fullstack creates a component?

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-fullstack

Im using angular-fullstack newest version I think "generatorVersion": "3.7.5", and right now I created a route

yo angular-fullstack:controller products and it created the files:

products.controller.js

products.controller.spec.js

products.js

products.scss

and when I tried

yo angular-fullstack:controller product_new_view

inside the folder /client/app/products it created a new folder 
/client/app/products/product_new_view 
which I think is ok but the question is why the controller definition is not inside a component as in /client/app/products/products.controller.js

```
angular.module('meanshopApp')
    .component('products', {
        templateUrl: 'app/products/templates/products.html',
        controller: ProductsComponent
    })
})();
```

instead is just

```
angular.module('meanshopApp')
    .controller('ProductNewViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Hello';
    });
```

does that mean that for every new view I need to create a route? cause I read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component and there it says

Components as route templates
Components are also useful as route templates (e.g. when using ngRoute). In a component-based application, every view is a component:

Im new to angular by the way

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well with 3.7.5.